# Organize paragraphs in Word / OO Writer / LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer

When I read articles I often copy sections of it to a LibreOffice writer document (or any other Word-like program) with the purpose of having an idea collection. Sometimes I tag these sections or give them a meaningful headline that summarizes their content.

Often I'm ending up with a 50+ pages document with quotes, pictures, inspirations, etc (= a mess). I'll then try to go back to merge similar headlines, copy them next to each other, expand on ideas and so on.  For now I'm using the navigator to identify similar headlines. Often there is a lot of restructuring and "getting my thoughts in order" sort of thing going on and it involves a lot copy & paste, scrolling back and forth and so on.

I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do that, for example to drag & drop a whole paragraph (identified by a headline?) next to another.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO a *word processing software* isn't the best choice for organizing ideas, web snippets and so on. So, i recommend thinking about alternatives:

- **Databases**: OpenOffice / LibreOffice Base would be a very powerful solution, but it requires some manual preparation (data structure definition, forms, queries, reports). Advantage: very flexible and powerful, also with lots of data. Disadvantage: Configuration.
- [**Notetaking applications**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notetaking_software): Evernote or [clones / alternatives like NixNote](http://alternativeto.net/software/evernote/?license=opensource) offer the functionality required; some come with browser plugins, allowing to take notes directly from web content.
- [**Mind mapping Tools**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_mapping) like [Freeplane](http://freeplane.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an application like [Mindmapper](http://www.mindmapper.com/main/main.asp), It organizes thoughts into a tree-like structure. All you would need to do is write a header in the appropriate place for the idea you want to save (ex. 'Technology', 'Health Science', 'Religion') or perhaps a subheader if you want to really avoid clutter ('PS4', 'Osteoporosis', 'Tao'). Then make a subheader that is the title of the article you are copying, and copy the article itself into the 'note' for the sub-header. Notes don't appear on the tree, they appear in a box beneath, so you don't clutter the screen and it's quite easy to navigate.

As a bonus, the software has plenty of options to arrange things the way you like.

This is a paid program but I'm sure you can find a free substitute somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, I'd recommend something like Photoshop for this type of workflow. If you label your layers and know the program well enough (I'd say a couple weeks of experience), you can do everything you've stated above: quotes, pictures, inspirations, text paragraphs with the ability to move and manipulate them in every way that a word processor can and more. You can always crop and save specific "zones" of information once you've completed a thought, and I dare say you may see your workflow turn to art.